# Visualizing a two-way weighted frequency table

Tags: r, plot, visualization

```
dat <- data.frame(gender = c("F","F","F","M","F","U"), vol = c(500,750,1250,NA,300,700),weight=c(1.36,0.67,5.22,1.67,1.15,1.29))

   gender  vol weight
1      F  500   1.36
2      F  750   0.67
3      F 1250   5.22
4      M   NA   1.67
5      F  300   1.15
6      U  700   1.29
```

If we have the above data frame and create a two way weighted frequency table:

```
library(questionr)
two_way <- data.frame(wtd.table(dat$gender,y=dat$vol,weights=dat$weight))
```

that looks like this:

```
 Var1 Var2 Freq
1     F  300 1.15
2     M  300 0.00
3     U  300 0.00
4     F  500 1.36
5     M  500 0.00
6     U  500 0.00
7     F  700 0.00
8     M  700 0.00
9     U  700 1.29
10    F  750 0.67
11    M  750 0.00
12    U  750 0.00
13    F 1250 5.22
14    M 1250 0.00
15    U 1250 0.00
```

What would be the best way to visualize this? Should I be using a different approach when visualizing weighted data like this?

Quick-R does mention:

> Use the vcd package for visualizing relationships among categorical data (e.g. mosaic and association plots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first idea would be to go with the `geom_count` (former `stat_sum`) function from the `ggplot2` package. Using it, you could plot your table with e.g. gender on the x-axis and vol on the y-axis. Than the frequency would be displayed as the size of the circle

```
ggplot(two_way, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2)) +
  stat_sum(aes(size=Freq))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've implemented this and it works great. Is there a way to make it clearer as to where the largest frequencies lie? Like for example, having the bubbles change color the higher the frequency in a heat-map style? Most of my variables have many levels and one tends to lose the overview.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is possible. But first) I am not very good ggplot2 hacker and second) this would be question on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(vcd)
library(magrittr)

xtabs(weight ~ gender + vol, dat) %>% 
  mosaicplot(shade = T)
```